# Get a column value in Telerik asp.net mvc grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik

I want to get the value of column[0] of row[0] from a telerik mvc grid in a Javascript function. I wonder how to do that?

```
   @{
    Html.Telerik().Grid<StationEvaluation>().Name("ManagementGrid")
    .DataKeys(dataKeys => dataKeys.Add(o => o.StationEvaluationID)).Groupable().
    Filterable().Pageable().Sortable().Localizable("fa-IR").
    DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding.Ajax()

            ...
            columns.Bound(o => o.StationEvaluationId);
            ...
    }

<script type="text/javascript">
function MyFunction()
{
// I want to get the value here!
}
</script>
```

Comment: @BahmanNihhhahah, Telerik uses the fact that any content (HTML, JavaScript, etc) inside ASP.NET Web Pages is in fact translated into a Response.Write-like call by the page compiler. Try to 'View page source' for your rendered page. What are the rendered control id's?

Comment: Hi Dave, thanks for the reply. The control's id is the same with grid's name as it must be. You are right, I must find the value in the rendered HTML, but I can't find it!

Comment: that's strange. can you find anything that resembles controls? possibly jscript enabled? maybe if you do a search for id's. I will ask some ppl in my office about their experience with telerik. see if i can get more recent insights.

Comment: as a completely unrelated matter, i recomend you make a stackoverflow meta account. You can make suggestions about feature changes there and interact with moderators hearing their ideas about where stack should go. Also, you get a 100pnt bonus to your stack rep score the first time u create another stack-exchange account and link them.

Comment: Thanks Dave, OK, I'll do it ASAP.

Comment: That was great Dave, Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is even much more simpler way of doing this.

All of the Telerik MVC widgets have a clear cut client site API. Here is the link to the Grd-Client Side API documentation:

http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/telerik-ui-components-grid-client-api-and-events.html

What you are looking for is a way to access the underlying data item bound to a row. The Grid client side API exposes dataItem property of the grid.

Lets say you wanted to get the underlying data object bound to first row - you will write the following code to access it:

```
var grid = $("#<ID of the Grid").data("tGrid");
// get the first table row
var tr = $("#Grid tbody tr:eq(1)"); // use eq(1) if the grid is scrollable or eq(0) if not to get the first row
// get the associated data item
var dataItem = grid.dataItem(tr);
```

Now the dataItem represent the underlying data object.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think your solution is better than mine.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer:

```
var mastergrid = $('#ManagementGrid');
var mypreciousvalue = mastergrid[0].childNodes[2].childNodes[2].childNodes[0].childNodes[0].innerText;
```

The rendered HTML of the grid is something like this:

```
<div class="t-widget t-grid" id="ManagementGrid">
  <div class=t-toolbar t-grid-toolbar t-grid-top">
       ...</div>
  <div class="t-grouping-header">
       ...</div>
  <table cellspacing="0">
      <colgroup>...</colgroup>
      <thead class="t-grid-header">...</thead>
      <tbody>
         <tr>
            <td> **MY PRECIOUS VALUE** <td>
            ...(other cells)
         </tr>
         ... (other rows)
      </tbody>
  <div class="t-grid-pager t-grid-bottom">
       ...</div>
 </div>
```